# Python Program keeps returning False

Tags: python, loops, return

My program keeps returning False, even if it has returned True already. Does somebody know what I did wrong and how I could solve this?

```
(route and target are both lists)



while len(route) > 1:
        for id in range(len(target)):
            if route[0] == target[id]:
                 route_is_contained_in_other_route(route[1:],target[id+1:])
        return False
if len(route)==1:
      if route[0] in target:
        return True
      else:
        return False
```

Comment: You are returning `False ` in your while loop. So after completion of for loop it will always return False.

Comment: show your sample input, to return True(you are expecting)

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not continue after `return False`, which is why it always does that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this is a recursive function (you left out the header). As such your code doesn't return the return value of any recursive calls. Compare to this:

```
def route_is_contained_in_other_route(route, target):
    while len(route) > 1:
        for id in range(len(target)):
            if route[0] == target[id]:
                return route_is_contained_in_other_route(route[1:], target[id+1:])
    return False
if len(route) == 1:
    return route[0] in target
```

So, it returns either False if the currently compared element of `route` is not contained anywhere in `target`, or the result of the last comparison of the last element of `route` against `target`, signalled by `len(route) == 1`.

Comment: """ Returns whether each road of the first route is contained in the target route.
    The order of the route should be respected, but the roads should not necessarily be used consecutively.
    (for example: ["AB", "BC", "CD"] is contained in ["ZA", "AX", "XA", "AB", "BY", "YW", "WY", "YB", "BC", "CD"])""" --> should be true

Comment: As user1016274 explained, I forgot the 'return' before the recursive statement, now it works...  THANKS A LOT!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it works for you. I'd be happy if you would accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a return statement your function does not continue.

But without a example it's hard to say, how the function should look like.
If I had to guess, I would say perhaps something like:

```
while len(route) > 1:
        for id in range(len(target)):
            if route[0] == target[id]:
                 route_is_contained_in_other_route(route[1:],target[id+1:])
                 return True
        return False
if len(route)==1:
      if route[0] in target:
        return True
      else:
        return False
```